# Как узнать абсолютную величину ячейки TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня окно принимает динамическое количество параметров, которые я складываю при помощи LayoutPanel. но как после формирования окна получить высоту каждой ячейки, чтобы найти размер формы, при котором все что я добавил в панель будет "влазить" в окно

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую!

Сначала находите нужный `Cell`, потом ищите его размер. Либо сразу ищите массивы ширин и высот для всех ячеек с помощью методов `GetColumnWidths()` и `GetRowHeights()`. Код ниже ищет размер одной конкретной ячейки, где расположен контрол `button1`.

```
 TableLayoutPanelCellPosition pos = tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(button1);
 int width = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths()[pos.Column];
 int height = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights()[pos.Row];
```